# How to filter by same select with two fields with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select box with some options to filter. I want to filter by two different fields cities and categories:

HTML:

```
   <select ng-options="c.id as c.name  for c in categories" class="form-control" name="categories" ng-model="categoriesFilter">
     <option value="">All</option>
   </select>

<select ng-options="o.id as o.name  for o in cities" class="form-control" name="cities" ng-model="citiesFilter">
  <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.categories = [
    {name : "Private", id : 2},
    {name : "Buisness", id : 1},
    {name : "Deleted", id : 3}
];
```

I filter like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : {city:citiesFilter|| 
undefined} | filter : {typeCust: categoriesFilter|| undefined} | filter : 
{deleted: categoriesFilter}">
```

Here is the full example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/vaf031mr/13/)

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259732/angularjs-filter-multiple-select-inputs

Comment: sorry, doesn't answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain filters

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: {city: citiesFilter || undefined} | filter: { typeCust: categoriesFilter || undefined}">
```

Full fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vaf031mr/16/